# How would I create a SplitView programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

I tried to follow someone else's code that I found on StackOverflow, but I can't get it to work, at all.

This is the code I tried to follow:
[For Iphone how to reference root view controller from currently loaded view, so view can be replaced/switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645454/for-iphone-how-to-reference-root-view-controller-from-currently-loaded-view-so)

I've really only worked with Single View layouts so this is pretty new to me, especially without doing it in IB. I will be using the new view for the Score page. I am retrieving content via WebKit for the scoreboard, and it will eventually have a form to input your name/initials and it will save your score so you can check how you rank up against others who have played it, and that is the information that I would like in the split view.

There is a ton of relevant code, and I'm not sure where the problem is exactly, so here is a link to a zip containing the xcode project and all relevant files.
http://mdl.fm/pixelated.zip

I know this requires a lot of effort on behalf of whoever helps me, so I just want to thank anyone who is willing to help in advance. I would really appreciate some tips on how to do this.

Comment: This needs to be broken into at least four different questions. (Or reported as duplicates of four).

Comment: Well the main question is how would I create a split view programatically? The others aren't pressing issues right now and can be handled later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that look like an interesting project you are working on!  Here is my suggestion for you.  For a nice template to follow, just create a new project in xcode.  Selected a master detail project and pick universal.  Apple will automatically generate a project for you with storyboards for both iphone and iPad. the ipad is a split view, so its an excellent reference.

After it is created, go take a look at the appDelegate.m.  You will find the logic there to identify if the device is iphone or iPad and how to initialize the root view controller.

It has storyboards to work with so you can view how they were setup and how view controllers were assigned.

One twist when working with splitview controllers is assigning which controller is the delegate.  The delegate listens for the rotation messages and acts on them.  Either controller can be the delegate but typically the smaller on manages the navigation stuff and the larger one that is always on screen is set as the delegate and manages the rotation events and button dance.

hope that suggestion helps.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think of something so simple. Hopefully I can get it all sorted out now, thanks again. +1